# Display canvas in front of player

Tags: unity, c#

*I have stuck in this simple problem but unable to understand that why i am unable to control it.*

I have these line of code which is displaying my canvas object in front of my player(**camRotationToWatch** object name in code) at certain rotation of the player.

```
if (camRotationToWatch.transform.localEulerAngles.x >= navigationCanvasXMinmumLimit && camRotationToWatch.transform.localEulerAngles.x <= navigationCanvasXMaximumLimit)
        {
            if (!navCanvasHasDisplay) 
            {

                navigationCanvas.SetActive(true);
                //Debug.Log(camRotationToWatch.transform.forward);
                Vector3 navCanvas = camRotationToWatch.transform.position + camRotationToWatch.transform.forward * navCanvasDisplayDistanceFromCam;
                navCanvas = new Vector3(navCanvas.x, 2f, navCanvas.z);
                navigationCanvas.transform.position = new Vector3(navCanvas.x, navCanvas.y, navCanvas.z);

                navigationCanvas.transform.rotation = camRotationToWatch.transform.rotation;

                navCanvasHasDisplay = true;

            }
        }

        else
        {
            //navigationCanvas.SetActive(false);
            if (locationPanel.activeSelf == false && infoPanel.activeSelf == false) {
                navigationCanvas.SetActive(false);
                navCanvasHasDisplay = false;
            }
        }
```

This code is actually work fine when **camRotationToWatch** object rotate from **down to up** and Canvas show at correct position but as I try to to rotate **camRotationToWatch** from **up to down** it display(active) Canvas at very top position. How can I restrict canvas to show at same position (*No matter player rotate from up to down or down to up*) but display on front of the player object?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `camRotationToWatch.transform.localEulerAngles.x` may represent the angle in a way you are not expecting. For example, -30 degrees is the same as +330 degrees.

I'll take a guess that you are expecting a negative angle when looking up, while Unity is returning a positive angle. Try replacing the first line of the code you pasted with this code:

```
float xFromCamera = camRotationToWatch.transform.localEulerAngles.x;
if (xFromCamera >= 180.0f) xFromCamera -= 360.0f;
if (xFromCamera < -180.0f) xFromCamera += 360.0f;

if (xFromCamera >= navigationCanvasXMinmumLimit && xFromCamera <= navigationCanvasXMaximumLimit)
```

(Note: I wasn't confident at first, so I decided to test this out in Unity. I set the x rotation of a transform to a negative angle in code, then read the same x rotation later. The returned angle was positive, 360 + my angle.)

Comment: i am much frustated just copy your code and now my canvas object not enabling even

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Frustration is an unpleasant part of programming. To find the bug, we need more information. Remove my change, and try using `Debug.Log` to print out the value of `camRotationToWatch.transform.localEulerAngles.x`. Perhaps examining the numbers that are printed out will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I am frustated because i am trying to solve this issue from last 4 to 6 hours and still not solve yet. additionally i think that you did n't get the question

Comment: I want to show my canvas at specific position but on in front of my player object. The canvas always show in front of the player but its postion should remain same. No matter i look at up or down.it should show in front of player but not move up and down

Comment: So, while the canvas is visible, you want it to remain in the same position on-screen the whole time?

Comment: yes i want it to remain whole time, but as user rotate from left to right or right to left so it should change it position according to the forward but same will not apply when forward goes up to down or down to up

Comment: Your code will only position the canvas one time, at the moment it becomes visible. To update the position (move left and right with the user), try removing the line `if (!navCanvasHasDisplay) `. Is that closer to the correct behavior?

Comment: yes you pickup right but this thing is for exaclty same reason

Comment: my UI is updating its poistion at right left but i want to restrict it at up and down

Comment: How do you want to restrict it? It is restricted now, by the `2f` in the line `navCanvas = new Vector3(navCanvas.x, 2f, navCanvas.z);`. What is the correct value to restrict it to?

Comment: actually 2f restricting it to  height correctly but i cant restrict x and z which is the problem

Comment: x and z are changing as my player move and main problem is this i cant restrict to specific value

Comment: You want to restrict x and z, but I don't know what the restriction is. Can you edit your question to describe exactly how the x and z should be restricted?